# Time difference between Dates Java?

Tags: java, date, java-8, timestamp, java-time

I have been using the legacy Date API to calculate time difference between two times in `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss` format.

Client sets the `requestExpirationTime` attribute in request and server has a validation check to ensure that "***RequestExpirationTime is not before current system time***".

**Client:**

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
Timestamp originatingTimestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());

// duration is offset 5minutes for exmaple

Timestamp requestExpirationTimestamp = new Timestamp(originatingTimestamp.getTime() + duration); 
request.setRequestExpirationTimestamp(simpleDateFormat.format(requestExpirationTimestamp));
```

**Server:**

```
try {
        Date systemTime = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

        String ret = request.getRequestExpirationTimestamp();
        if (ret != null) {
            Date requestExpirationTimestamp = sdf.parse(ret);
            if (requestExpirationTimestamp.before(systemTime)) {                    

            logger.info("Request timedout: RequestExpirationTime is before current system time");

                }
            }
        }
```

This code is giving issues as the `systemTime` on server comes in IST (Indian Standard Time) and client can send in any UTC/IST.

I have now moved to Java 8, so I can leave the legacy Date Api in Java.

How can I ensure such Timezone issues don't come in my code ? I tried setting timeZone in 
SimpleDateFormat on the server but the `new Date()` is behaving differently on different servers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider to use the new Date and Time API (ZonedDateTime or Instant) and a framework such as Jackson (JSON) or JAXB (XML) to marshall and unmarshall the dates.

Comment: If the client is sending dates in `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss` format, you've got no way of knowing what the time zone or time offset is.  You'll need to use a format at the client end that includes the time zone or time offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the client sends time that is not in UTC, for example India Standard Time (IST), and the server doesn’t know which time zone the client used, then there is nothing the server can do to make it work correctly. Instead I suggest that you make sure that the client sends time in UTC always.

**Client**

Make sure you always send time in UTC:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss");

    String requestExpirationTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .plusMinutes(5)
            .format(formatter);

    System.out.println(requestExpirationTime);
```

Example output from running just now:

> 20200506T183409

**Server**

Now the server knows the time is in UTC. I am assuming that it is using a formatter identical to the one the client used.

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(requestExpirationTime, formatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    OffsetDateTime systemTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    if (dateTime.isBefore(systemTime)) {
        System.out.println("Request timedout: RequestExpirationTime is before current system time");
    } else {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
```

> OK

**Tip**

You may append `Z` to your timestamp string to make it explicit that it is UTC. It might prevent some mistakes further down the road.

> 20200506T183409Z

Comment: What if the client sends time in IST or any other timezone, then above logic won’t work ?

Comment: Bingo, @SiddharthTrikha, that’s the core of the problem: If the client sends time that is not in UTC and the server doesn’t know which time zone the client used, then there is nothing the server can do to make it work correctly. This is why I suggested that you make sure that the client sends time in UTC always.

Comment: Yes, unless we include timezone in the current date format ‘yyyyMMddTHHmmss’